# MySql same calculation in select and where

Tags: mysql

I have a query which looks like this

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2 
FROM
  table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.col = t2.col 
WHERE expensive_func () < 10
```

This runs fairly quickly @ 0.110 seconds. But if I want to also show the result of `expensive_func()` so change the query to

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2,
  expensive_func() as col3
FROM
  table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.col = t2.col 
WHERE expensive_func () < 10
```

This works but the query time is now ~0.550

using explain on both query's returns exactly the same (confirmed by diff)

is there any way to re use expensive func ?

I assume its slower because it has to store the result of expensive func ? as its more than twice as slow (what I would expect to be a maximum)

EDIT:

Just in case version 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log is what I'm using.

Edit2:

Removing `expensive_func()` from the WHERE doesnt seem to make a difference in the second query in terms of time, it returns more rows but in the same amount of time.

Edit3:

For some reason using the mysql CREATE FUNCTION slows it down, taking the code out of the function and putting it in the query makes it much faster.

Comment: What the `expensive_func()` do for? Try to create an simple UDF like return a constant then test again.

Comment: Its a distance calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expensive_func` was a stored function. Replacing the stored function with the contents of the stored function makes the query run in ~0.080 seconds. a huge improvement.

I'm not sure why the stored function made everything much slower but it seems the only downside is slightly less maintainable MySQL code.